# Django добавить комментарий к посту

Tags: django

Подскажите как сделать добавление комментариев к посту, то что сделал вываливается в ошибку 405. И так что сделано:

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор комментария')
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Комментарий')
    com_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания комментария')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комментарий'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'
```

views.py

```
class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    fields = ['comment']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Понимаю что не хватает параметров для валидного запроса, но не могу понять как их вытащить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не заполняете такие поля, как `content_type` и `object_id`.

Объекты для них можно получить следующим образом:

```py
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(post)
object_id = post.id
```

, где `post` — это модель, к которой будет привязан комментарий.

Насколько я вижу, Ваше представлении не имеет никакого понятия о том, что комментируется. Вы должны передавать в него также данные, по которым можно получить запись модели `post` из примера.

Вот пару способов, как это можно сделать:

- Извлекать информацию из `URL` (так как речь идёт о `post_detail.html`)
- Передавать скрытым полем формы

Comment: То есть я правильно понял в шаблон в форму добавил <input type="hidden" id="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}"> и во вьюшкке должно быть     def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        post = Post.objects.get(self.request.post_id)
        form.instance.object_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(post)
        form.instance.object_id = self.request.post_id
        return super().form_valid(form)

Comment: @AlexUa Идея верна, но реализация немного не та. Во-первых, получить информацию из запроса напрямую не получится, она лежит в словаре `POST`: `post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')`. А получение экземпляра модели делается так: `post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)`. С шаблоном всё хорошо.

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку, Я новичок в этом деле, стараюсь разобраться, но что то не получается реализация  def form_valid(self, form):
        post_id = self.request.POST.get('post_id')
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.object_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(post)
        form.instance.object_id = post_id
        return super().form_valid(form)  - почему то дает 405 ошибку

Comment: @AlexUa Вы приняли ответ, у Вас получилось? Если нет, то я мог бы повторить Ваш проект и залить пример на `GitHub`.

Comment: Не знаю почему все равно вываливается ошибка 405

Comment: @AlexUa Ошибка `405` не связана с представлениями. Скорее всего, Вы ошиблись в `URL`. Проверьте, что и в `urls.py`, и в шаблоне правильно проставлены слеши `/` (особенно на конце, это важно) и что путь вообще существует.

Comment: Да не туда добавил path в urls.py. Спасибо за помощь.